# me da este error (const client = new discord.client({ intents: [discord.intents.flags.guilds, discord.intents.flags.guild_messages] })

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

***soy nuevo a la hora de programar me ha salido este error a la hora de intentar cargar los comandos del bot de discord  y, no se como arreglarlo llevo mas de 3h buscando haber si encuentro el error o como arreglarlo pero no se como hacerlo si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería la verdad***

***el error que me da pone esto (const client = new discord.client({ intents: [discord.intents.flags.guilds, discord.intents.flags.guild_messages] })***

si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco (discord monxxu)

***syntaxerror: identifier 'client' has alredy been declared***

***es en JavaScript***

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('El bot está listo.');

  const guildId = 'id server'; // Reemplaza con el ID de tu servidor
  const channelId = 'id chanel'; // Reemplaza con el ID del canal de normas

  const rules = `
  - Seguir las normas oficiales de Discord: https://discordapp.com/guidelines
  - Seguir los terminos y condificiones de Discord: https://discordapp.com/terms
  - No ser tóxicos ni discriminar a la gente por su religión, raza, política, etc.
  - No hacer mic-spam, ni gritar, ni molestar (esto incluye con los bots de música) en los canales de voz.
  - No hacer ningún tipo spam sin el permiso del staff.
  - Esta prohibido spammear en los chats de texto y usar las MAYÚSCULAS excesivamente.
  - Los moduladores de voz solo están permitidos con el permiso de un miembro de Staff 
  - No hagáis ping a ningún miembro del staff sin algún motivo importante. Son personas.
  - Está prohibido el uso indebido y faltas de respeto por el chat General del servidor y a otros jugadores a través del chat de voz o mensaje directo.
  - Mencionar o escribir al Patrón y Bros&Sis será penado con baneo inmediato.
  - No hagáis ping a un moderador sin ningún motivo importante son personas.
  - Está terminantemente prohibido grabar el discord es motivo de baneo.
  `; // Coloca las normas del servidor aquí

  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
  if (!guild) return console.error('¡Servidor no encontrado!');

  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  if (!channel) return console.error('¡Canal no encontrado!');

  channel.send(rules)
    .then(() => console.log('Normas enviadas al canal de normas'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error al enviar las normas:', error));
});

// Aquí debes poner tu token de Discord
client.login('token');




en el eventhandler tengo esto puesto

async function loadEvents(client) {
    const { loadFiles } = require("../Functions/fileLoader");
    const ascii = require("ascii-table");
    const table = new ascii().setHeading("Events", "Status");
  
    await client.events.clear();
  
    const Files = await loadFiles("Events");
  
    Files.forEach((file) => {
      const event = require(file);
  
      const execute = (...args) => event.execute(...args, client);
      client.events.set(event.name, execute);
  
      if (event.rest) {
        if (event.once) client.rest.on(event.name, execute);
        else client.rest.on(event.name, execute);
      } else {
        if (event.once) client.once(event.name, execute);
        else client.on(event.name, execute);
      }
  
      table.addRow(event.name, "");
    });
  
    return console.log(table.toString(), "\nLoaded Events.");
  }
  
  module.exports = { loadEvents };
```

type here

[image: me da ese error cuando intento cargar el bot]

Comment: En lugar de decir "tengo un problema al...", pon el error en cuestión en el título mismo de la pregunta. Además, pon siempre el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden leer las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Y no sé qué tiene el _eventHandler.js_, pero [la documentación](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#common-client-initialization-changes) da pistas del problema.